# error in woocommerce payment

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, payment

For some reason, I dnot know which, my clients are with this error: http://prntscr.com/jrsg2j
I dont know if is the worpress, woocommerce or another plugin or the payment platform we use here in the company, the Vindi.

Someone give me a light? It does not happen to everyone, it's a customer or another one! We have already tested several methods of payments here and this problem has never arisen for us, it only happens with a customer. And also does not vary according to the price or ticket or card, the error comes completely random.

I cant identify the error because it happens only with clients. It is not with the same product, nor with the same price, nor with the same payment method, it is completely random. I have tried to reproduce the error in several ways and I can not find the problem.

Help?

Comment: I've tried to take a look, and it seems that on iOS devices (I've tried with Safari) the  page `/finalizar-compra/` has a different layout than other devices, [here's a screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/O9YC4WO) with Android (left) and iOS (right). You probably have some plugins which loads the page's layout based on os/browser?

Comment: I think the problem happens when the person ends the purchase and will select the payment method because the error always appears on top of "Ticket (Boleto)"

Comment: if you have the possibility, try to complete a payment on an iOS device. Because the payment option in Safari was already visible in the Login page, while in Android (and Desktop) it was not. [Just took this from iOS](https://imgur.com/a/EKydcY7)

Comment: Ok, how I fix this? Please ♥

Comment: You can send a me the source code where the error appears?

Comment: Not sure what causes this. Do you have different checkout pages?

Comment: Btw to reproduce it I've just added to the basket a product from the homepage, clicked on the cart and finally clicked on "fechar compra", [this is the result](https://imgur.com/a/yWhG1ZX), and [here's](http://jsfiddle.net/y4sox1L0/) the source code of the page. (ps: please add @ + username to answer)